# Remove whitespace from a wordcloud plot

Tags: r, word-cloud

Below is a screenshot from quarto document with a wordplot I've generated using wordcloud package in R.
The challenge is that there is a lot of white space between the words on the plot and the border of the plot image.
How do I reduce the size of the extra 'white space'?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the white space might be way more complex than these two options! Hope that can help as well.

1. You can change the size of the letters with the wordcloud2 package and fill in the white space.

Example: `wordcloud2(data=demoFreq, size=1.6)`

2. You can save the image without the white space and upload it manually in Quarto.

Example: `![Image1](file_name.png)`